# Upload image to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: xml, cloud, storage

I am trying to use the XML API for GCS to add files to my bucket. I couldn't find any topics that solved my problem. I have used the "PUT Object" method on this page: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#putobject.

I get this error when I try to run the xml:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty Below is a rendering of
>   the page up to the first error.

This is my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
GET /ali.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: mybucket.storage.googleapis.com
Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```